# Python : How to pass sys.argv to the list of .py files?

Tags: python, argv, sys

I have a below code where I am trying to pass sys.argv[1] to all my python scripts using date as parameter. The objective is to run from the command line. But its not picking up the date inside file1.py, file2.py and file3.py. Please suggest.

```
command line: python C:\user\auto.py 03-Jan-2020

#code: auto.py

date = str(sys.argv[1])
print(sys.argv[1])
#reading python scripts
scripts_list = [r'C:\user\file1.py', r'C:\user\file2.py', r'C:\user\file3.py']

output_list = [r'C:\user\out1.py', r'C:\user\out2.py', 
r'C:\user\out3.py']

input_processes = []
output_processes = []

for script in scripts_list:
    p = subprocess.Popen(['python', script])
    input_processes.append(p)    

for p in input_processes:
    p.wait()

for script in output_list:
    p = subprocess.Popen(['python', script])
    output_processes.append(p)    

for p in output_processes:
    p.wait()
```

Comment: `sys.argv[1]` is already a string, you don't need to call `str()`.

Comment: Show how you're executing the scripts in `scripts_list`.

Comment: Why are you doing this with Python? It's a trivial shell script.

Comment: `for script in $scripts_list; do python $script "$1"; done`

Comment: @Barmar.. I have created the list to run file1.py, file2.py parallelly using 'subprocess' library. To do so, I have to create list of python files to run.

Comment: You can use GNU Parallel to run scripts in parallel from the command line.

Comment: @Barmar, I have extended my code for your reference.

Comment: I assume `input_scripts` should be `scripts_list`.

Comment: Someone already answered the question. Didn't that show how to solve the problem?

Comment: @Barmar. I have edited the scripts_list.

Comment: @Barmar Someone didnt show how to pass sys.srg statement in the scripts_list.

Comment: why use `subprocess.Popen` in order to call other py code?

Comment: @balderman my subprocess function is working fine. Please show, how to pass sys.arg in the 'scripts_list' or 'output_list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through your list calling each script and passing the arg.

```
import subprocess
for s in scripts_list:
    subprocess.run(['python', s, date])
```

Comment: please show how you are passing sys.arg statement in the 'scripts_list'

Comment: @John83 The argument is the date variable.